# Pascal Triangle in OCaml: Get next line as a list

Tags: list, recursion, functional-programming, ocaml, pascals-triangle

I am trying to get an OCaml function which gives the next line of a Pascal's triangle as a list for example:

(next_line: int -> list -> int list)

let get_next_line [1;1] returns [1;2;1] and so on.

I tried something like this but don't know how to go forward:

```
let rec next_line lst acc = match lst with
| [] -> [1]
| hd::tl -> (* need directions here *)
```

[image]

Comment: Each number is the sum of the previous and next number of the previous line. The next number you get from `hd` but you lack the previous number. You have to add an extra parameter to `next_line` for that. It also makes sense to pass the previous line as last argument because then you can write: `let rec aux acc last = function [] -> acc @ [1] | hd::tl -> ... let next_line = aux [] 0`. Or was `acc` supposed to be the previous number instead of an accumulator of the result?

Answer (score 1):

If I have a list `[1; 1]`, how do I get to `[1; 2; 1]`? Well, imagine if I added `0` to the beginning of the list, then added `0` to the end of the list, so I had two three element lists: `[0; 1; 1]` and `[1; 1; 0]`.

I could probably write a recursive function or find one in the standard library which adds respective elements of the two lists and gives me `[1; 2; 1]`.

If I could accomplish that, then repeating the same with `[1; 2; 1]` would give me `[0; 1; 2; 1]` and `[1; 2; 1; 0]` and then `[1; 3; 3; 1]` would be the sum of those two.